# second order differential equations, Dirichlet Laplacian, eigenvalue of rectangle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplacian

How would i go about solving this equation

$$\frac{-b''(y)}{b(y)}+\frac{-a''(x)}{a(x)}=\lambda$$

I've attempted to set $$\frac{-a''(x)}{a(x)}=\mu$$ where $\mu$ is an arbitrary constant. and then solve using separation of variables, however, i can't seem to solve for $\mu$. My plan is to use this to then solve

$$\frac{-b''(y)}{b(y)}=\lambda +\mu$$

Could somehow explain if im going about solving this the right way and if yes help me, if no explain how i can do this to solve for $\lambda$

**If i've made any major errors or missed information in the above or if someone just wants to know where this is coming from i'm trying to solve The Eigenvalue Problem for the Rectangle where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for the Dirichlet Laplacian**

Comment: The equation you are trying to solve is homogeneous second order ODE and it's quite easy to solve them - do you not know the method ?

Comment: @user160738 It's not an ODE. This is a two dimensional elliptic PDE.

Comment: Along each line $y=c$, $\frac{a''(x)}{a(x)}$ is constant. Depending on the value of this constant, there may or may not be nontrivial solutions to this *ordinary* differential equation. (In the Dirichlet case, when solutions exist, they will be sinusoids.) Similarly, on each line $x=c$, $\frac{b''(y)}{b(y)}$ is constant, and depending on the value of this constant, there may or may not be nontrivial solutions to this ordinary differential equation. So call the $x$ eigenvalues $\xi_n$ and the $y$ eigenvalues $\eta_m$.

Comment: You have a different eigenspace for each $m,n$, with the eigenvalue $\xi_n+\eta_m$.

Comment: @Ian this is beginning to make sense, so i would have to solve this based on each line $x$ and $y$. then add up both spectrums. could you explain a little more about how i would go about solving the problem though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve

\begin{align}
\left\{\begin{array}{l} \Delta f(x,y) = - \lambda f(x,y) \qquad \text{in} \,\, \Omega \\ f(x,y) \Big|_{\partial \Omega} = 0 \end{array}\right.
\end{align}

where $\Omega$ is a rectangle. By assuming that $f(x,y)$ is separable, i.e.

$$f(x,y) = a(x) b(y)$$

you get

$$\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = b(y) \frac{\partial^2 a(x)}{\partial x^2}+a(x)\frac{\partial^2 b(y)}{\partial y^2} = - \lambda a(x) b(y)$$

Separating the variables yields (now in your notation)

$$\frac{a''(x)}{a(x)} = -\frac{b''(y)}{b(y)} - \lambda$$

The left side solely depends on $x$, the right side solely depends on $y$, since $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue in $\Bbb R$. So this equation can be fulfilled only if both sides are constant, i.e.

$$\frac{a''(x)}{a(x)} = -\frac{b''(y)}{b(y)} - \lambda = \mu \qquad \mu \in \Bbb R$$

So you get two equations

$$a''(x) - \mu a(x) = 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad b''(y) + (\lambda + \mu) b(y) = 0$$

These are well-known second-order ODE's. So basically you're more or less right in your attempt. You can then determine $\lambda$ and $\mu$ by solving these ODE's and thus obtain $f(x,y) = a(x) b(y)$. Applying the boundary conditions on the obtained $f(x,y)$, you'll get conditions for the constants $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ of the solutions of these two ODE's. Keep in mind that you probably seek solutions, where $f(x,y) \not\equiv 0$ holds. Finally, you'll get equations out of the boundary conditions, where, in order to be fulfilled, it must hold that either $f(x,y) \equiv 0$ (which you probably don't want) or $\lambda$ (or $\mu$) is of a particular form.

Comment: I have solved the two ODE's in order to find $a(x)=A\exp(x\sqrt{\mu})+B\exp(-x\sqrt{\mu})$ and $b(y)=C\exp(y\sqrt{-(\lambda+\mu)} + D\exp(-y\sqrt{-(\lambda+\mu)} ) $. how do i use this to get conditions on A,B,C,D?

Comment: That's right, but I would write $b(y)$ in the form $b(y) = C \cos(\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y) + D \sin(\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)$ just for convenience. You have the Dirichlet condition $f(x,y) \big|_{\partial \Omega} = 0$. So, if $L$ and $L'$ are the two different side lengths of the rectangle and we set the lower left corner as $(0,0)$, you have that $f(0,y) = f(x,0) = f(L,y) = f(x,L') = 0$ for $x \in [0,L]$ and $y \in [0,L']$. Four conditions for four constants.

Comment: could you explain how you got that $b(y)=C\exp(y\sqrt{-(\lambda+\mu)} + D\exp(-y\sqrt{-(\lambda+\mu)} ) = C \cos(\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y) + D \sin(\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)$

Comment: To be honest, I should have said that $b(y) = \hat{C} \cos (\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y) + \hat{D} \sin (\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)$ since the the constants in my version are not the same as in yours (i.e. the equation in your comment doesn't hold). But $b(y) = C \exp(\sqrt{-(\lambda + \mu}) y) + D \exp(-\sqrt{-(\lambda + \mu}) y) = C \exp(i\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)+D \exp(-i \sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)$. Then use $e^{ \pm i x} = \cos (x) \pm i \sin (x)$ and factor out $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)$ and $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda + \mu} y)$ and define the new constants $\hat{C} = C + D$ and $\hat{D} = i (C-D)$.